Adding path prefix for React and Nginx app
Premise: I have a React and Node.js app that I use with Docker. It runs on my server with Nginx and it works. However, I now want to introduce a path prefix after the domain name, so instead of somedomain.com it should use somedomain/prefix
I am unable to make it work. I get a white page in the browser and console logs:

Loading module from “somedomain.com/prefix/assets/index-BcocU_L-.js” was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“text/html”)
The stylesheet https://somedomain.com/prefix/assets/index-Cp6etric.css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”

Here are my relevant configuration and code files (I marked comments where I changed something).
vite.config.ts
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    host: true,
    port: 5173
  },
  plugins: [
react
()],
  envDir: '../',

  // added this
  base: '/prefix/'
})

nginx.conf
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name somedomain.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name somedomain.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/privkey.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    # added this
    location /prefix/ {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://api:3000/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
}

AppRouter.tsx
const router = createBrowserRouter([
        {
            path: "/",
            element: <Layout/>,
            ...
        },
    ],
    {
        // added this
        basename: "/prefix"
    }
);

Dockerfile (for the UI)
FROM node:20 as 
build
ARG 
VITE_API_URL
ARG VITE_ENVIRONMENT
WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build


FROM nginx:stable-alpine as 
production
COPY --from=
build 
/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html

COPY --from=
root 
nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

In the Docker container I have the static **index.html **as follows:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    ...
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="/prefix/assets/index-BcocU_L-.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin href="/prefix/assets/index-Cp6etric.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>

The assets directory itself is under /usr/share/nginx/html.
Those JS and CSS files are not accessible from:
https://somedomain.com/prefix/assets/index-BcocU_L-.js
But from:
https://somedomain.com/assets/index-BcocU_L-.js (without prefix in the path)
Any ideas how I should change my configuration? Am I missing something here?
Tried different configurations, but couldn't found the right one.
